# Nested Ifs are bad? Use functions with return instead?

Tags: c#

I read somwhere that lots of nested IF statements show your thinking about a decision the wrong way. After looking at 100 lines of my own code I agree, but im unsure how to make it better. So im making multiple decisions based on multiple objects. IE

```
IF X == Y AND Z != 1
    IF X > Y OR Q IS null
       foreach (var item in Collection)
          IF item > z
```

I understand you could make specific functions out of the conditions which then return true/false for each but im not sure how this is cleaner. Can you use "return" inside an If statement to condense into a single code block? I understand this example is a little obtuse but im just looking for general principles.P

Comment: Eh, if `X == Y` (1st `if`) how can be `X > Y` (2nd `if`) then?

Comment: In this case, first and second *if*'s could be unified into a single one through *AND* between them. And moving the tests into separate functions will produce much readable code due to the fact that *CanWithdrawFromAccount* is much more understandable than *X==Y AND Z != 1*, for example.